# Visualizing marginal effect of two-way interaction of binary logistic model in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm, interaction

Can someone suggest a quick and comprehensible way of how to visualize a two-way interaction of a glm model/ binary logistic regression model, using ggplot? I'm interested in the marginal effect!

I have looked at other posts, but did not really understand them. Another issue is that I cannot use ggpredict/ gginteraction because of by R-version (3.4.2).

My data structure looks like this (simplified):

```
region_AB   motive   voter_attribute  vote_for_party_XY
1           1        1                1
1           0        1                1
1           1        0                0
0           0        0                0
0           0        1                0
0           1        0                0
```

And I'm claiming (and actually finding) that there region mediates the effect of a given motive on voting for party XY.

Now I know this is not a reproducible example. But maybe someone can come up with a one fits all solution (at least for the case of two-way interactions of glm models). If necessary and it helps, maybe the `mtcars` dataset can serve examplary purposes: [there's even an example for an interaction-term model using this dataset](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/171426_7cf80261bab24149a18ba47573e73d24.html).

I'm hoping someone has a nice and easy solution to this. This could be a general guide for visualizing marginal effects of two-way interactions...

Comment: How to visualize interactions will depend on the data types - it looks like your data is all binary, is that correct? And the voter_attribute isn't relevant to your question? Also the `mtcars` example you link to doesn't seem to use `ggpredict` or `gginteraction`, and it includes a plot of the effect of the interaction between `wt` and `am` - what more are you looking for than this example?

Comment: Well most are binary, some aren't such as age. The two parts of the interaction term are both binary, though. Region on the one hand and satisfaction with one's income level (I recoded that one into a binary variable from a 5-point scaled variable if I'm not mistaken).
The mtcars example actually was a bad choice. I don't think that they plotted the marginal effects of an interaction term of a glm object...
Do you know any quick solution to this?

Comment: No, I'm still trying to figure out if you know what you want or if you're looking for someone to tell you what you want. If you know the result you are looking for, you should describe it in your question. If you don't, then I think this isn't really on-topic here, maybe you should be asking at stats.stackexchange instead. I also think appropriate visualizations could be pretty different depending on whether the interaction is between two continuous variables, two categorical variables, or one of each, which is why I find it strange you're not being very specific about that in your question.

Comment: If it's just 2 binary variables, it hardly seems a visualization is necessary, a 2x2 table would seem nice and concise. Maybe a heatmap would work generally for two categorical variables. For continuous:categorical, I'd probably do a plot just like the one in your `mtcars` link. For continuous:continuous, a levelplot might be best.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/index.html) to compute marginal effects. The return value is a data frame, but there's a `plot()`-method that creates/returns a ggplot-object. Here'a an artificial example with binary outcome, but you can find more details in the "Articles" from the above referenced website.

```
library(ggeffects)
library(sjmisc) # to preserve labels
data(efc)

# prepare data, create binary outcome and make
# numeric variables categorical
efc$neg_c_7d <- dicho(efc$neg_c_7)
efc$c161sex <- to_factor(efc$c161sex)
efc$c172code <- to_factor(efc$c172code)

# fit logistic regression
m <- glm(
  neg_c_7d ~ c12hour + c161sex * c172code,
  data = efc,
  family = binomial(link = "logit")
)

# compute and plot marginal effects
ggpredict(m, c("c172code", "c161sex")) %>% plot()
```

[image]

Note that the dataset I used [is labelled](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjlabelled/index.html), that's why the axes are annotated with "proper" value and variable labels.