# issue with creating bar plot from logistic regression results

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to plot the interaction results of a logistic regression where my independent variable (gbg) is binary and my moderator is binary (gender). The interaction terms is gender*gbg. Here is the code for the logistic regression I ran.

```
model <- glm(y ~ gender + lunch + cohort + race + gbg + gender*gbg, data = data, family = binomial)
```

Sample output is here:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.02336    0.20860  -4.906  9.3e-07 
gender      0.20342    0.15663   1.299   0.1940    
cohort      0.07891    0.13436   0.587   0.5570    
race        0.08707    0.18150   0.480   0.6314    
gbg         0.22623    0.20622   1.097   0.2726    
gxgbg      -0.76378    0.30647  -2.492   0.0127
```

I know how to plot interaction results when at least one of my IVs or moderators are linear, but I don't know how to do it when both are and my outcome is binary.  I tried this and no luck

```
plot_model(model, type = "int")
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: This model doesn't have interactions, right?

Comment: Yes, the gxgbg is the interaction.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but I thought you would specify an interaction like `gender:gbg` in your model formula.

Comment: Thanks, I just revised my code above to clarify.

Comment: Check out this post. `ggeffects` is a terrific package! 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51131499/10556787

Comment: Thank you @MagnusNordmo! I really appreciate it!